# Allowing remote tomcat debugging on 8000 port in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I have an application deployed in tomcat on a google Ubuntu VM.
Application is running fine and accessible remotely by domain name and IP address.
I want to debug this application remotely using Eclipse from another Ubuntu system. On google VM I am starting the tomcat with command,

```
catalina.sh jpda start
```

In tomcat log i can see,

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

I guess that means remote debugging is enabled on 8000 port. But when I try to connect to application from Eclipse for remote debugging it gives **'connection refused'** error.
When I try telnet remotely it gives,

```
ivish@ivish:~$ telnet host_ip 8000
Trying host_ip ...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

I have replaced actual IP address with host_ip above.

Output of nmap is as follows,

```
google@vm:/opt/tomcat8$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-19 05:27 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
5432/tcp open  postgresql
8000/tcp open  http-alt
8009/tcp open  ajp13

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

Any idea how can i successfully remote debug the application?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Output of 'sudo iptables -L' command on Google VM.

```
google@vm:/opt/tomcat8$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
sshguard   all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain sshguard (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Output of 'sudo iptables -L' command on local Ubuntu sytem.

```
ivish@ivish:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Do you have a local firewall rule or does the VM have a security group rule that is blocking access?

Comment: Hello Eric, i am not very familiar with linux environment. But i will try and investigate if firewall is blocking the port.

Comment: I think you should be able to do `sudo iptables -L` to see your rules, and if you do so please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1125793/edit) your question to include that information

Comment: Ok, local firewalls don't seem to be it, does Google have a concept of security groups or similar that will affect network access to your VM, much like a firewall at that layer.  I know AWS has such a thing, so I assume Google does too

Comment: I see. I will get in touch with Google customer support for help then. Thanks @Eric

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to suggest that you may use ufw command set in order to see what you have.

Here is the link for ufw;

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

If the port is not enabled, you may run below command to enable to port;

Check what you have

> ufw status

Enable to port

> ufw allow from any to any 8000

And apply the change

> ufw disable &&
>   ufw enable

In addition to this, you may check ubuntu server Security Groups settings. In
most cases, ubuntu servers does not allow to acces many port like 8080. So, you may also edit Inbound Rules to enable 8000 port.

Comment: Thanks @oisleyen. I will try your suggestions and let you know.